# Google-Chrome-Stable not launching

Tags: 14.04, google-chrome, google

Installed google-chrome-stable from stack exchange through Ubuntu Software Center.  Worked fine, yet today it would not launch, from launch bar or command line.  I am a newbie to Ubuntu and the command line.  I am using Ubuntu 14.04 and need help.  Thx.

Comment: What is the result of command `google-chrome`?